# Pre store big amount of data in app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a big amount of data (more then 100 entries) to show on a table view. The data will be static, so i was thinking in store it on a plist file. The problem is when it is shown in table view, the user will be able to select or deselect a row and this information must be stored.

In other words the app will have a list of things and the user can select the things he own.

What's the best way to store the data in the app and the selected information?

PS.: I was avoiding Core Data, but if this is the best way how can i pre store the data in an entity?

Comment: If the only thing you need to change on the data is the selection, you can easily have a separate file to store the selected indexes (either store in a plain file, with indexes separated by ';', either use a `NSArray`+plist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to track the selected and unselected row is here:
this code will save value with your tap on the cell.

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BOOL isSelected=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[indexPath.row stringValue]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:!isSelected forKey:[indexPath.row stringValue]];
```

}

Comment: And what if the app has second user?

Comment: I thought of that before, but i was afraid that using User Defaults for to many entries was too much, but as the data would be only Booleans i think it's fine. All solutions here are great, but this one is really simply and i'm kind of running out of time. Petro, in my case the app allows only one user, so that's fine =)

Answer (score 2):

100 entres isn't actually a large amount of data.

I would be inclined to use a plist for this small amount of data.

If you wanted, you could keep the user-data in the same plist too:
When app first runs it could copy the plist to the document directory so that it can be edited (the ownership data written).

Or, you could use a separate plist for the user-data.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best way", but one viable approach is to use a JSON file. If the data isn't too large, say the JSON file is much less than 1 MByte.

Creating and modifying a JSON file is quite comfortable in an editor. You can parse and create a representation as usual with `NSJSONSerialization`.

**Hint**: A JSON file which has N number of bytes, creates a representation of Foundation objects which roughly need a total of 5*N to 10*N allocated space.